# Appium TouchAction/ MultiTouchAction don't work when testing Mobile Web

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, appium, java-client

I'm trying to set up an automated test for a mobile website using Appium 1.2.4, Java-client 2.0.0, Selenium 2.42.2 and a real device (Samsung Galaxy Tab-3).

The problem is that, whenever I'm trying to use Touch Actions (e.g. `driver.swipe()` or `driver.pinch()`) I'm getting a `Not Yet Implemented …` error.

I've tried to improvise by switching the driver context to `NATIVE_APP` before executing the TouchAction and yet it still didn't work (I get a different error: `An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command`).

Would appreciate your kind advice.

Configuration:

- Selenium 2.42.2 Java-client 2.0.0 Appium 1.2.4
- Device:Galaxy Tab3
- OS: Android 4.4.2
- Browser: Chrome 38

Thanks and Best Regards,
Daniel.

```java
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.setCapability("device","ANDROID");
capability.setCapability("app", getValidBrowserName(browser));
capability.setCapability("newCommandTimeout",150);
capability.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capability.setCapability("deviceName", "GalaxyTab3");
capability.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");

RemoteWebDriver driver = null;
Platform currentPlatform = desiredCapabilities.getPlatform();
boolean isMobilePlatform = currentPlatform.equals(Platform.ANDROID) || currentPlatform.equals(Platform.MAC);

URL hubURL = new URL(hubHost + "/wd/hub");

try {
    driver = isMobilePlatform ? new AndroidDriver(hubURL, desiredCapabilities) : new RemoteWebDriver(hubURL, desiredCapabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(waitTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(scriptTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
}

catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to create Selenium WebDriver instance on hub: "
        + hubURL.toString() + " with capabilities: "
        + desiredCapabilities.toString() + "\n"
        + e.getMessage());
    }



WebElement buttonTest = driver.findElement(By.id("configBtn"));
int buttonX = buttonTest.getLocation().getX();
int buttonY = buttonTest.getLocation().getY();

((AppiumDriver)driver).swipe(buttonX, buttonY, buttonX + 70, buttonY + 70, 1000);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of the code.

Comment: Added sample code portions.
Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: Added code to the main message.
Thanks for the help, Daniel.